# <p></p> tags appears out of nowhere

Tags: development, templates, joomla-3.5

I was editing my theme until something came up. Some paragraphs attributes appears between modules of my homepage.

Here is what's happening in image :

[image: Space between mods]

When I delete them through firebug, it's working and the space in the design disappear.

But how can I delete them for good in the source code ? Where do I find the place where thoses tags are really located ?

They doesn't seems to appear in my mods when I look at them with the editor in the backend.

Sorry for my english, I hope I was clear, if not don't hesitate to ask me some details.

*Joomla 3.5.1 with Artista Theme.*

Thank you

Comment: @AlternateChris You mentioned that the tags are appearing within your modules- I think that that is your answer. You will need to check the module jsn-mod-custom as it seems to be placing the tags in your page. Edit it to remove them.

Comment: @oooooo Thanks for your feedback. I've checked and the module jsn-mod-custom is actually a module where you can add the html code you want. You know, go to Modules > New Modules > Custom HTML. I didn't find where I can make change to that global fonction. When I look at the code of a specific module for exemple the part below the space. There is no <p> tags anywhere. And those came from anywhere. Even if I rollback all my changes at a moment where those spacing where not there, there still here... Really weird

Answer (score 2):

So, after looking for a while... I've change this, under :

Extensions > Plugins > Editor - TinyMCE > New lines

Change the attributes for New Lines from "P Elements" to "BR Element".

But doing only that didn't change anything. I went through every articles and modules on my homepage and delete any space or line break at the end and beginning of each one.

It solved it.

Comment: Just for clarification: The html code is stored in the database, therefore changing the new line element in the editor doesn't automatically change it in the already made articles or modules with custom html input for example. I had the problem too, I had to remove those p-elements from the row entry in the database, they didn't appear in the editor view or in the toggled view neither.