# Joomla editor field wraps two <p> tags when saved

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have a joomla form which contains an editor field in it. When I toogle the  editor and paste a html code and save it why does the two p tags appear

```
<field name="template" type="editor" label="TEMPLATE" description="DESC_ALERT_TEMPLATE" required="true" cols="150" rows="20" filter="raw" width="95%"/>
```

```
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered" style="height: 344px;" width="891"></table>
```

How to remove the two p tags while saving the form and when I open the form again and save it, it wraps two more p tags before

```
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered" style="height: 344px;" width="891"></table>
```

Comment: This is old advice, so I don't know if it still works: https://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/joomla/22-how-to-stop-tinymce-to-add-the-paragraph-tag.html  This one is even older: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=624785  If you have already found these while researching or you have tried a few techniques which failed, please include this as part of a complete question.  Possible dupe of: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/17015/12352

Comment: No. Both these fixes aren't working for my case. In the case of articles it is working properly. I tried to debug the code of com_content but didn't find any concrete solution for it.

Comment: I think you're looking in the wrong place. That sort of bug is almost certainly caused by the editor plugin, not com_content.

Comment: In addition to naming which editor you're wrestling with, it would also help if you checked whether the extra tags are being added in conversion from code to window or on save to the database. You can do this by toggling to paste in the HTML, toggle it back to WYSIWYG mode, then back again to HTML and see if the extra p tags are present at that point.